# Decrypting a very simple key

Tags: authentication, cryptography, md5

I'm doing a basic cryptography course and a question is asking to to decipher:

> Wmd5emhzIHhya3N2aSBkemggbGlydHJtem9vYiBkaXJnZ3ZtIHVsaSBnc3YgU3Z5aXZkIHpva3N6eXZnIHptdyByaCB6IGhrdnhyem8geHpodiBsdSBnc3YgenV1cm12IHhya3N2aS4gR3N2IHVvenQgcmggemd5NGhzMWhoMGgxbmtvMw==

I tried to analyse the capital letters to make sense of it, but couldn't get anything. Apart from the repeating occurrence of md5, I can't seem to make any sense of it. Any help will be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: I suggest you go back over the course material until you find the techniques that they taught you (and want you to use) to solve this problem.

Answer (score 3):

The trailing `=` usually proposes that it is encoded (not encrypted!) using `base64`. You can decode it simply as from Linux shell (or there are some web tools):

```
echo "Wmd5emhzIHhya3N2aSBkemggbGlydHJtem9vYiBkaXJnZ3ZtIHVsaSBnc3YgU3Z5aXZkIHpva3N6eXZnIHptdyByaCB6IGhrdnhyem8geHpodiBsdSBnc3YgenV1cm12IHhya3N2aS4gR3N2IHVvenQgcmggemd5NGhzMWhoMGgxbmtvMw==" | base64 -d
Zgyzhs xrksvi dzh lirtrmzoob dirggvm uli gsv Svyivd zokszyvg zmw rh z hkvxrzo xzhv lu gsv zuurmv xrksvi. Gsv uozt rh zgy4hs1hh0h1nko3
```

Later on, there will be probably some other kind of encryption, since it does not look like English so far.

Comment: Looks like a simple substition cipher. Start by analyzing what the most common letters are in your language and replace occurrences in the ciphertext. The last part looks like its a password given the use of digits.

Comment: I wanted to leave something for the OP, not to spoil his homework completely. :/

Comment: @Jakuje understood :)

Comment: sorry, hope you still have fun with it :(

Answer (score 1):

This is a **base64** encoding followed what seems to be a **substitution cipher**. Since it is monoalphabetic, it should be easy to crack. Have fun:

http://www.cryptoclub.org/tools/substitution_cipher.php